# Map subdomains with virtual urls in apache or nginx?

Tags: django, apache, nginx, reverse-proxy

So i came up with a requirement that i have my complete application and assume it runs on mysite.com , it has various components like store , team etc .

so urls will look like (these all urls are virtual - i am using django its similar to mapping urls with related functions , for example there is no actual directory with name "store" or "team" ):

---

1) mysite.com/store/1/Shoes

2) mysite.com/store/2/Clothing

3) mysite.com/team/1/Marketing

4) mysite.com/team/2/Business

5) mysite.com/team/3/CustomerCare

---

So Now i have two sub domains :

a) team.mysite.com

b) store.mysite.com

Requirement is : 
whenever there comes a request like store.mysite.com/1/Shoes it open up content of  page : mysite.com/store/1/Shoes

Similaly if request come from team.mysite.com/1/Marketing it will open up content of page : mysite.com/team/1/Marketing

So in both the cases above the subdomain should remain intact in browser.

How to do something like this in nginx or apache (will prefer nginx) ?

Comment: This I think should go to serverfault and this is not the duplicate you think. This is to be Dynamic in nature. For example if the user creates a new page, it be available as a sub domain. I am not good with Nginx but it seems the way to go.

Comment: Would be ai interesting place ot start with: http://serverfault.com/questions/524833/regular-expressions-in-server-name-with-nginx-vhost

Comment: @ziyan junaideen  : the link you provided and the problem i have is different , i dont have any directory , i just have virtual urls.